# Unable to keep default auth.user in field of table between logouts in web2py

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite, web2py

In my db.py file I have defined a table called recipe with a field as Field('cook','string',default=auth.user.username) which basically creates a recipe with an uploaded image and username. It works fine but whenever I logout I get an error saying ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'username')

Answer (score 0):

`auth.user` is `None` when the user is not logged in, so you cannot try to access the `.username` attribute in that case. To avoid the problem, just add some conditional logic:

```
default=auth.user.username if auth.user else None
```